# innerhtml of a select tag does not update selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select name="cs_position_id_1034362" id="cs_position_id_1034362" class="cs_position_id">
    <option value="1034314">1</option>
    <option value="1034315" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="1034316">3</option>
    <option value="1034317">4</option>
    <option value="1034318">5</option>
    <option value="1034319">6</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("body").on("change", ".cs_position_id", function(){
    var cs_select = $(this);
    var cs_select_html = cs_select.html();
    alert(cs_select_html);
});
```

Once this runs the selected attribute of the html does not reflect the actual selected value? 
Can anyone explain how this works?

Comment: You do not have anything setting the value of the select. Only the variables change

Comment: "*Why does the inner html of the select tag not get updated ?*" - because you're not updating it anywhere. Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve, a necessary detail which seems entirely left out of your question.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do as changing your select's HTML is probably a *really bad* option :)

Comment: cs_select.val("1034318");

Comment: Side note: Please also avoid using delegated events with `'body'`. Use `document` instead as `body` has a bug that will stop mouse events if the computed body height is 0 (depends on styling). `document` has the added bonus of always existing, even before DOM ready so you can wire them up without a DOM ready handler :)

Comment: I don't even understand what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i am trying to understand how this html() works. I would like to see <option selected="selected">33 </option> if i select 33

Comment: But there is no option with a value of 33, so where would that option come from in the first place?

Comment: It was a terrible example if it doesn't illustrate your problem and uses information not present in your question. What should happen, then, if I select the option with the text of `4`, and `value="1034317"`?

Comment: Updated the question, i dont actually care about the value

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nao2tvxm/?

Comment: Are you looking at the actual HTML ('view source') to see if the change has happened, or at the DOM (using the developer tools, right-click -> inspect element)? Because the underlying HTML will never change, but the DOM will show the `selected` attribute on the newly-selected `<option>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the difference between the *property* and the *attribute*.

A simpler example would be working with `<input type="text" value="Default value" />`

Type something in it. You will be able to observe that the *attribute* does **not** change. `.getAttribute("value")` (jQuery `.attr("value")`) will continue to return `Default value`. However the `.value` *property* (jQuery `.val()`) **does** change, giving you whatever you typed.

The same principle applies to your drop-down. This is why the jQuery selector is `:selected`, rather than `[selected=selected]`. The first one gets the *currently selected* option, whereas the second gets the *option that was selected by default*.

Comment: Got it , so the attributes are static in a document unless you set them using jquery?  I Did not know that .. what a noob